# Pullback composed with pushforward of a line bundle under closed immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$. Denote by $i:X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^3$ the natural closed immersion. Is it true that $i^*i_*\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{L}$?

Comment: $i$ is affine, so you can reduce to the affine case. But there we have $M \otimes_A A/I \cong M/IM$ and indeed $IM=0$, if $M$ was a priori an $A/I$-module. Note that the conclusion is wrong, if the morphism is only finite or affine (in that case the natural morphism is only surjective).

Comment: @Moos: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the direct computation work: For any affine open set $U \subset X$, we have $$(i^*i_*\mathcal{L})(U)=\lim_{f(U) \subset V} f_*\mathcal{L}(V) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(U)=\lim_{f(U) \subset V}\mathcal{L}(V \cap X)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(U)$$ which is the same as $\mathcal{L}(U) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ because there exists an open set $V \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ such that $U=V \cap X$ (using the fact that the topology on $X$ is the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{P}^3$). If I understand correctly this should give a proof of the question (use that there is a natural morphism from $i^*i_*\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{L}$ which is isomorphic on every affine open set).

Comment: I think one has to be careful here a little bit: This shows that there is an isomorphism $\mathcal G \to \mathcal L$, where $\mathcal G$ is the presheaf, that $i^*i_*\mathcal L$ is associated to. Since sheafification does not affect the stalks, this is still an isomorphism after sheafification.